# Which Azure storage management jar to use

Tags: java, azure, azure-java-sdk

I noticed that Azure's Java SDK has several maven dependencies which seem to be targeting the same thing, for instance, the following artifact ids:

- azure-management-storage:0.8.0
- azure-mgmt-storage:0.8.0
- azure-svc-mgmt-storage:0.8.0

It's the same with network and compute.

Does anyone know what's the difference between those?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use azure-svc-mgmt-storage jar.

I reviewed the maven repository page of "azure-management-storage" http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-management-storage. Microsoft has renamed the artifact to "azure-svc-mgmt-storage". It's the same with network and compute.

For azure-management-storage, azure-mgmt-storage and azure-svc-mgmt-storage, I recommend you refer to this document:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/wiki/Azure-SDK-for-Java-Features

Best Regards.